# codeigniter form_open is undefined

Tags: forms

I'm new in codeigniter. I tried something but I got an error which is form_open is undefined function. How can I solve this? Thanks you.

Here is my code.
This is my Blogview which is in view folder.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Title</title>

  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
     <p class="bg-success"><?php echo $isim; ?></p>
     <?php echo form_open('blog', array('class' => 'form-horizontal')); ?>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Adınız:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
     <?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'isim', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
     <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Gonder', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
     </div>
     </div>
     <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```